# i want your help abut program to run automatically every 12 hours

Tags: python, twitter, save, tweepy

I'm doing a tweepy crawling.
I want the program to run automatically every 12 hours
Could you tell me the syntax?
I'm doing it with Python, and I have all the tweepy crawling code.

Comment: which syntax? `Python`'s?

Answer (score 1):

You can try executing/calling your program by the command line interface and schedule a task using the embedded in windows- Windows Scheduler. There are many alternatives but that is the easiest I found when I did  such task few months ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "schedule" library

to install, on terminal enter:

```
pip install schedule
```

here is an example of the code you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I am doing this job!")

schedule.every(12).hours.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

or you can read the documents to see the other functions [Click Here](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

good luck!